# On the 2-rank of an integer matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

Let $A$ be a $0$-$1$ matrix of order $n$. Is the following assertion true?

Conjecture: $ AA^T\equiv 0\pmod{4}$ implies that $rank_2(A)\le \lfloor\frac{n}{4}\rfloor$, where $0$ is the zero matrix, $A^T$ is the transpose of $A$, and $rank_2(A)$ is the rank of $A$ over the binary field.

It is easy to construct an $0$-$1$ matrix $A$ with $rank_2(A)= \lfloor\frac{n}{4}\rfloor$.  Indeed, the following constructions for small orders can be easily generalized to any order:

\begin{pmatrix}
1&1&1&1\\
0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0\\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1&1&1&1&0\\
0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0\\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1&1&1&1&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0\\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1&1&1&1&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1&1&1&1&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&1&1&1&1\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
\end{pmatrix}
This means that the above conjecture is best possible (if true). Note that a similar assertion is a simple exercise in Linear Algebra:
$ AA^T\equiv 0\pmod{2}$ implies that $rank_2(A)\le \lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor$

How to prove the conjecture above?

Comment: Some clarifications -- you say $A$ is "of order n".  In this context this typically means $A$ is $n\times n$ but you then give an example under "easy to construct..." that is not square, which is a contradiction.  My read is $A\in \mathbb Z^{n\times n}$ and you want to look at it under two different ring homomorphisms (applied component-wise) that send the integers to characteristic 2 and 4.

Comment: Thanks for your clarifications. I have edited the question accordingly.